# How to enforce order of initialization with static member variables

Tags: c++, oop

Lets say I have a Base class with **static** member variable X, which is initialized as usual.
Then, I have a Sub class that inherits from Base, with a **static** member variable Y.

I want to initialize Y **by using X's value**, but that creates a problem - I have no way of knowing wheather X will be initialized before Y, so Y might use a garbage value instead of X's real value. I also get a clang-tidy warning because of that.

One solution is to just assign to Y in the c'tor, but that kind of negates the point of a static member variable. I don't want to assign to it everytime I create an object.

And so it won't be an XY question - my purpose is to introduce a variable, that all classes that inherits from Sub, would share.

Edit: those classes are defined in their own .cpp files, therefore those initializations can't see each other.

Comment: Don't use variables with static storage duration at all if possible. Failing that, prefer static variables local in functions to static class data members. This solves most cases of static initialisation order fiasco. That is, instead of `static int X = 42;` write `static int& X() { static int x = 42; return x; }`

Comment: If they are in the same translation unit the first one is initialized first.

Answer (score 4):

One solution is to wrap the static variables in static functions. The variables are allocated on-demand, thread-safe

```
class Base
{
protected:
    static const std::string& X()
    {
        static std::string x = "Hello";
        return x;
    }
};


class Sub : public Base
{
public:
    static const std::string& Y()
    {
        static std::string y = X() + " World!";
        return y;
    }
};
```

Answer (score 1):

I would manage to initialize your static variable within the same translation unit (e.g. .cpp file) where the order of initialization is from top to bottom without ambiguity. Thus avoiding the "[static initialization order fiasco](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/siof)".